# Similar OnEdit and OnEdit2 Scripts not working together

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a Google Scripts function in Google Sheets to copy rows from one sheet to another based on certain criteria. In essence, I want to move "Requests" into an Archive or into a Confirmed pool. From the Confirmed pool, I want to move them into the archive when they are completed.

I have tried moving the code around in several ways, including separating it out into different scripts and keeping it in the same script. Portions of the code work at the same time--for example, I can usually move Requests into the confirmed pool or into the archive. Initially, I thought that the problem was that I was using the same column in different sheets. I changed that, but it didn't fix the code. Then, I found that multiple "onEdit" scripts cannot run in the same sheet, so I changed the name of one of them to onEdit2 and then to "myBookingRequests." That change didn't work either.

The code tends to break when I attempt to move anything from the confirmed pool into the archive, so I think now that the problem is I am moving lines into a sheet and taking lines from the sheet. Any help on how to troubleshoot this or remove conflicts from the codes would help. Thank you.

Two Scripts Separated:

1. ```
       function onEdit(event) {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
       var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

          if(s.getName() == "Booking Requests" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "Y") {
           var row = r.getRow();
           var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
           var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Confirmed Bookings");
           var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
           s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
           s.deleteRow(row); }

         if(s.getName() == "Booking Requests" && r.getColumn() == 13 && r.getValue() == "Y") {
          var row = r.getRow();
          var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
          var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archived Bookings");
          var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
          s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
          s.deleteRow(row); }
       }
   ```
2. ```
   function onEdit2(event) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange(); 

    if(s.getName() == "Confirmed Bookings" && r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == "Y") {
     var row = r.getRow();
     var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
     var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archived Bookings");
     var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
     s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
     s.deleteRow(row); }

   if(s.getName() == "Confirmed Bookings" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Y") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archived Bookings");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row); }
   ```

   }

Combining the scripts is simple, as I just have to add the two extra if clauses back under the same heading.

I haven't gotten any actual error messages, so I assume that some parts of the code are negatively interacting with others. Any help on preventing the code from conflicting would be great. Thanks.

(Also, I'm very inexperienced. I only do this when I need to make functional spreadsheets for work.)

Execution Log after separating out the problem area (Booking Requests -> Confirmed Bookings):

```
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:610 CDT] Starting execution
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:617 CDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:618 CDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:619 CDT] Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:620 CDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:620 CDT] Spreadsheet.getActiveRange() [0 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:693 CDT] Sheet.getName() [0.072 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:694 CDT] Range.getColumn() [0 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:788 CDT] Range.getValue() [0.093 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:788 CDT] Range.getRow() [0 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:875 CDT] Sheet.getLastColumn() [0.086 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:876 CDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Confirmed Requests]) [0.001 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:975 CDT] Sheet.getLastRow() [0.098 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:976 CDT] Sheet.getRange([995, 1]) [0 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:977 CDT] Sheet.getRange([4, 1, 1, 12]) [0 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:54:977 CDT] Range.copyTo([Range]) [0 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:55:084 CDT] Sheet.deleteRow([4]) [0.106 seconds]
 [19-07-03 14:20:55:094 CDT] Execution failed: The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet. (line 12, file "Code") [0.47 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Include the execution transcript in the question, this can be found by going to `View > Execution transcript`. Here you can see what the script is doing and any error messages that you might be missing.

Comment: Create a single script, and configure it as an Installable Trigger.

Comment: Just to clarify - having two versions of onEdit running at the same time is asking for trouble. A better solution is to combine them in some way and also create an installable onEdit trigger.

Comment: I've run your code-okay. Combined your code-okay; Ran the code as a simple onEdit(event) trigger-okay. You noted that there are no errors in the Execution transcript, so I don't think there is a problem in the code. I wonder if there you are doing something that you haven't described in your question. E.g., you said _The code tends to break when I attempt to move anything from the confirmed pool into the archive_ What do you mean by this; what you mean by "break"; what you mean by "move". BTW, would you please share your spreadsheet (or at least a non-confidential version of it).

Comment: @Tedinoz It helps to know that the code is functioning properly for others. By "break," I mean that it stops working where it was previously working fine. By "move," I mean the copyTo function and deleteRow functions that essentially move one line to another sheet. 

I realized that if I deleted the "confirmed" sheet and the added it again, the code would work temporarily again. I'm going to try to put it in another worksheet entirely and see if there was just some kind of glitch. If that doesn't work, I'll create a version of the spreadsheet on my personal account and share that. Thank you!

Comment: @Tedinoz I found that the problems were actually occurring when it came to the code dealing with the Booking Requests sheet. Everything can be moved to the archive, but the code can't find the Confirmed sheet. I'll copy the execution transcript here. It seems that it thinks that something is out of domain.

Comment: @FaithWalker I've added my onEdit FYI. Run the code and then review the Logs - it ought to enable you to identify where, why and when the code is "breaking".

Comment: @FaithWalker The Execution transcript refers to 'Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Confirmed Requests])'; Both your code (and mine) refer to `Confirmed Bookings`. "Confirmed Requests" Vs "Confirmed Bookings" - could it be just an error in the name of the sheet?

Comment: @Tedinoz I wish! I copied and pasted the exact characters from the sheet name into the code. It's just an error on my part writing this summary.

Comment: @FaithWalker The "problem" is the use of `targetSheet.getLastRow()`; this returns row 955. There are two aspects: 1) you are trying to copy to a non-existent row (`targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1`), and there is a question about whether you actually have 955 rows of data on "Confirmed Bookings" or whether there might be a formula that is copying to the bottom of the page and distorting the value of "LastRow". Both are easily fixed. So, first: do you have 995 rows of data?

Answer (score 0):

This code is a single onEdit(e).

The code works as proposed by the OP, and includes numerous `Logger` statements that would enable the OP to troubleshoot values at various stages and identify the cause of any errors.

---

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var eVal = event.value;
  var eSheet = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var ecolumnStart = event.range.columnStart;
  var erowStart = event.range.rowStart;
  var erowEnd = event.range.rowEnd;
  var ecolumnEnd = event.range.columnEnd;
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the spreadsheet is "+event.source.getName()+", the sheet = "+eSheet);
  Logger.log("DEBUG: Range details - Column Start:"+ecolumnStart+", Column End:"+ecolumnEnd+", Row start:"+erowStart+", and Row End:"+erowEnd);
  Logger.log("DEBUG: The Range = "+event.range.getA1Notation()+", and the value = "+eVal);
 //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(event))

  // STEP#1
  // Sheet=Booking Requests
  // AND
  // column = L (12)
  // AND
  // value = "Y"

  if(s.getName() == "Booking Requests" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "Y") {

    Logger.log("DEBUG: step 1 - if worked");

    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    Logger.log("DEBUG: row = "+row+", number of columns = "+numColumns);

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Confirmed Bookings");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    Logger.log("DEBUG: target range = "+target.getA1Notation());

    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row); 
  }
  else{
    Logger.log("DEBUG: step 1 - if failed");
  }

  // STEP#2
  // Sheet=Booking Requests
  // AND 
  // Column = 13 (M)
  // AND
  // VALUE = "Y"

  if(s.getName() == "Booking Requests" && r.getColumn() == 13 && r.getValue() == "Y") {

    Logger.log("DEBUG: step 2 - if worked");

    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    Logger.log("DEBUG: row = "+row+", number of columns = "+numColumns);

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archived Bookings");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    Logger.log("DEBUG: target range = "+target.getA1Notation());

    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row); 
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.log("DEBUG: step 2 - if failed");
  }

  // STEP#3
  // Sheet=Confirmed Bookings
  // AND
  // column = N (14)
  // AND
  // value = "Y"
  if(s.getName() == "Confirmed Bookings" && r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == "Y") {

    Logger.log("DEBUG: step 3 - if worked");

    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    Logger.log("DEBUG: row = "+row+", number of columns = "+numColumns);

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archived Bookings");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row); 
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.log("DEBUG: step 3 - if failed");
  }

  // STEP#4
  // Sheet=Confirmed Bookings
  // AND
  // column = O (15)
  // AND
  // value = "Y"


  if(s.getName() == "Confirmed Bookings" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Y") {

    Logger.log("DEBUG: step 4 - if worked");

    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    Logger.log("DEBUG: row = "+row+", number of columns = "+numColumns);    

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archived Bookings");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row); 
  }
   else
  {
    Logger.log("DEBUG: step 4 - if failed");
  }
}
```

---